# Find minimum numeric value and return cell in different row

Tags: google-sheets, filter, formula, spreadsheet, minimum

I am looking to find the minimum (numeric value only) of a multi-column range that will have numbers and text values in it and then return a cell from the same column in Row 1.

For example:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Dave | Ryan | Nate |
| 2 | 7 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | Apple | 1 | 8 |
| 9 | 10 | Orange | 12 |
| Banana | 14 | Kiwi | 16 |

I want to first find the minimum numeric-only value in A2:D5 (which would be 1) and then return the value/cell that corresponds with that column in Row 1 (which would be Ryan).

I tried the follow formula but it wasn't working properly.

```
=INDEX(A1:D1,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:D5),A2:D5,0)))
```

Comment: there's a new tab mk.help with an arrayformula solution if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for min value only:

```
=INDEX(MIN(A2:D5))
```

[image]

and:

```
=+INDEX(SORT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(A2:D5*1)=MIN(A2:D5), A1:D1, ))))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:D1&"♦"&A2:D5), "♦")&""}, 
 "order by Col2 limit 1"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you as always! I used the second formula for what I needed. Works perfectly 